# grouping and summing items of list using java 8 streams

Tags: lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

Suppose that I have a **`List<Banana> bananas`**. Where Banana class is defined like bellow :

**Banana.java**

```
public class Banana{
   String name;
   Long weight;
   Long price;
   // getters & setters
}
```

the **bananas** list contains :

```
[
   {"banana1", 10, 20}, 
   {"banana1", 10, 20}, 
   {"banana1", 10, 20},
   {"banana2", 20, 30},
   {"banana2", 30, 30},
   {"banana3", 50, 40},
]
```

what I want to do here is to group by banana's name where summing weight column & price column (each alone) so that I can have this result :

```
[
   {"banana1", 30, 60}, 
   {"banana2", 50, 60},
   {"banana3", 50, 40},
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group them with `Collectors.toMap` using the merge function:

```
Map<String,Banana> bananasByName =
    bananas.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Banana::getName,
                                     Function.identity(),
                                     (b1,b2)->{ 
                                                 b1.addWeightAndPrice(b2); return b1; 
                                              }));
```

Where `addWeightAndPrice` is an instance method of the `Banana` class that adds the weight and price of the passed `Banana` to the `Banana` instance on which it is called.

If you don't want to mutate the original `Banana` instances, you can change the merge function to create a new `Banana` instance and add to it the weight and price of the two input `Banana` instances.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran)'s answer with a full, tested implementation via [the java online compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Java8ForEachExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //creating sample Collection
        List<Banana> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(new Banana("B1",5,30));
        myList.add(new Banana("B1",3,60));
        myList.add(new Banana("B2",1,30));
        myList.add(new Banana("B2",4,20));
        myList.add(new Banana("B2",7,100));
        // Eran's code here:
        Map<String,Banana> bananasByName =
        myList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Banana::getName,
                                     Function.identity(),
                                     (b1,b2)->{b1.addWeightAndPrice(b2); return b1;}));
        // End of Eran's code
        bananasByName.entrySet().forEach(e -> { 
           System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue()); 
        });
    }

}

class Banana{
   private String name;
   public int weight;
   public int price;
   public Banana(String name, int weight, int price) {
       this.name = name;
       this.weight = weight;
       this.price = price;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public int getWeight() {
       return weight;
   }
   public int getPrice() {
       return price;
   }
   public void addWeightAndPrice(Banana other) {
       this.price +=other.getPrice();
       this.weight +=other.getWeight();
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return (new StringJoiner(", ")).add(name).add(Integer.toString(weight)).
          add(Integer.toString(price)).toString();
   }

}
```

Output:

```
B2 : B2, 12, 150
B1 : B1, 8, 90
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, I would have liked to up-vote your response, but unfortunately I can't :(

Comment: Well, hopefully some other generous SO user will be inclined to do so.
Regardsless - I hope this answer helps you out, buddy.

Comment: While `StringJoiner` is a useful tool, it’s use here is not really convincing compared to the simple `return name + ", " + weight + ", " + price;`.

Comment: @Holger : not the main issue here, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is similar to this: 
I simplify solution by breaking it to three step.due to defined `BiFunction` and `Function` for it.

**first function**

this `BiFunction` get two Banana object and return single Banana object that summing expect properties.(price,weight)

```
 BiFunction<Banana, Banana, Banana> function =
            (o1, o2) -> new Banana(o2.getName(), o1.getWeight() +o2.getWeight(),
                                   o1.getPrice() + o2.getPrice());
```

**and second function**

this function get list of Banana object and return single Banana.

```
  Function<List<Banana>, Banana> function2 =
            l -> l.stream()
                  .reduce(new Banana("",0l,0l),(o1, o2) -> function.apply(o1, o2));
```

**and finally**

```
    List<Banana> bananaList = bananas.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Banana::getName)).values()
            .stream()
            .map(function2::apply)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

```
 List<Banana> bananaList = bananas.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Banana::getName)).values()
            .stream()
            .map(bananas1 -> bananas1
                    .stream()
                    .reduce(new Banana("",0l,0l),
                            (banana1,banana2)->new Banana(banana2.getName(),
                                                 banana1.getWeight() + banana2.getWeight(),
                                                  banana1.getPrice() + banana2.getPrice())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```